# Bugzilla could not connect to the mysql?

Tags: bugzilla

I am using C:\Bugzilla>checksetup.pl and it shows me this error message...plz tell me how i connect to mysql with bugzilla....

There was an error connecting to MySQL:

```
Access denied for user 'bugs'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

This might have several reasons:

- MySQL is not running.
- MySQL is running, but there is a problem either in the
  server configuration or the database access rights. Read the Bugzilla
  Guide in the doc directory. The section about database configuration
  should help.
- Your password for the 'bugs' user, specified in $db_pass, is
  incorrect, in './localconfig'.
- There is a subtle problem with Perl, DBI, or MySQL. Make
  sure all settings in './localconfig' are correct. If all else fails, set
  '$db_check' to 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to grant access to the user bugs from localhost to this database.  Try the following, replacing the relevant parameters

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASENAME.* To 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

More information about [GRANT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html)